# Fixed buttons dissappear behind elements in google chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm have a wordpress site where I have three buttons with `position:fixed` in the right side. The buttons show fine in FF and IE, but disappears behind the next section when I scroll in google chrome. I am pretty sure it is a stacking context problem, but can not make the button appear no matter which value I change.  HTML and css below( the theme uses visual composer, if that is any help:)

```
.button_fixed{
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:35%;
z-index:99999999;
}

.button_fixed a{
border:3px solid #f37121;
border-radius:8px 0 0 8px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
display:block;
border-right:0;
color:white;
margin-bottom:25px;
padding:10px;
font-family: 'Deftone Stylus';
font-size:35px;
width:150px;
position:relative;

}

span.oswald{
font-family: Oswald;
font-size:25px;
text-transform:uppercase;
displaY:inline-block;
padding-top:5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button_fixed">
<a href="#">sell <br/><span class="oswald">equipment</span></a>
<a href="#">buy <br/><span class="oswald">equipment</span></a>
<a href="#">outsource <br/><span class="oswald">my sales</span></a>
</div>
```

site url: http://tinyurl.com/q9yangh

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `#top` add `overflow: visible`

Comment: Thanks! It works! can you explain why chrome was behaving like that?

Comment: Glade I could help, because you have overflow hidden for .mk-page-section, same class you have in #top